# Converting keystrokes gathered by onkeydown into characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I try to convert keystrokes into chracters.
In other question someone recommand to use the onkeydown function because onkeypress gets handeled differently by different characters.

I don't know how to handle special chracters like ´ ` ' ( ) that might be different in different keyboards around the world.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For keys that have printable character equivalents, you should use the `keypress` event because you can retrieve character codes from the `keypress` event, which is generally not possible for `keyup` and `keydown` events.

The event properties you need are `which` and `keyCode` - pretty much all browsers have one or both of these, though IE muddies the waters by using `keyCode` for the character code while some other browsers return a (different) key code. Most non-IE browsers also have `charCode` but it seems all such browsers also have `which`, so `charCode` is never needed. A simple example:

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
  var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  alert(charStr);
};
```

Here is a [useful reference page](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html).

Comment: Basically that means that I have to handle printable chracters with onkeypress and the rest (like the delete key) with onkeydown?

Comment: Yes. If it's just the delete key it should be fine - I believe the keyCode is 46 in most browsers and keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.onkeydown = checkKey;
function checkKey(e) {

e = e || window.event;
document.getElementById("label").style.display = "none";
if (e.keyCode == '65') {
    //a
    var lx = document.getElementById('location');
    typeIt("a");
}
else if (e.keyCode == '66') {
    //b
      var lx = document.getElementById('location');
    typeIt("b");
}
else if (e.keyCode == '67') {
   //c
      var lx = document.getElementById('location');
    typeIt("c");
}
}
```

This should successfully convert the key code you press into a string letter, which you can use in a bigger function. It takes more time, but I found it is highly compatible with most browsers and keyboards (whatever the language may be.) I used this code in a text editor project which would be distributed to friends in several countries, so I am certain it will work. Note: the function above only includes the letters "A", "B", and "C".

Comment: Note: This code works with an HTML element with the id of "location", and refers to a function called typeIt("LETTER") to analyze whether or not the text should be bold, italicized, or underlined.